# Why OnRowEditing is required even though it has no logic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

The buttonfield with command EDIT doesn't work until I put

```
OnRowEditing="grdviewContractorTypes_RowEditing"
```

Problem:

I wrote this code

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdviewContractorTypes" OnRowEditing="grdviewContractorTypes_RowEditing" OnRowCommand="grdviewContractorTypes_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="pk_ContractorTypes_ContractorTypeID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="pk_ContractorTypes_ContractorTypeID" HeaderText="ID" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ContractorTypeName" HeaderText="Contractor Type" />
                                            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="edit" ImageUrl="~/assets/global/images/shopping/edit.png" ButtonType="Image" ControlStyle-Width="25px" ControlStyle-Height="25px" />


                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
```

.cs

```
protected void grdviewContractorTypes_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "edit")
            {
                byte ContractorTypeID = Convert.ToByte(grdviewContractorTypes.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value);

                //HFActID.Value = ID.ToString();

                btnAddContractorType.Visible = false;
                btnUpdated.Visible = true;

                DataTable dt = MngContractorTypes.SelectContractorTypesByContractorTypeID(ContractorTypeID);
                DataRow r = dt.Rows[0];

                txtBoxContractorTypeName.Text = r["ContractorTypeName"].ToString();
                HdnFieldContractorTypeID.Value = r["pk_ContractorTypes_ContractorTypeID"].ToString();
                //txtSearch.Text = "Testing...";
                //Response.Write("DONE");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(Convert.ToString(ex.Message));
        }
    }
```

The above code runs when I click button field with 'edit' command in DEBUGGER but doesn't do anything in actual, on screen until I put this.

```
protected void grdviewContractorTypes_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Data-bound controls recognize certain command names and automatically raise and handle the appropriate events for the control. Refer this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.commandname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: So what should I do to prevent this from happening, since it changes the gridview to editable which I don't want to happen

Comment: Just change the default command name "edit" to "cmdEdit" etc..

Comment: Post your answer in ANSWER box so I could accept